# Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found with make command line build

Tags: ios, bash, qt, shell

I have a Qt app which builds for iOS on an OSX machine. It builds & runs fine from QtCreator. But I also need to be able to build it command line using following command which I run in a bash script.

`qmake MyProject.pro -spec macx-ios-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=iphoneos CONFIG+=device CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler`
`make`

It builds all fine but last step fails erroring as:
`Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.`

How can I resolve this code sign error of iOS ?

Comment: Qt Creator sets up a different PATH and might also set up other env. variables for an iOS target. You'll need to dump env. variables from within qmake, by running a command at qmake-time.

Comment: @Kuba Over. Is there a sample you can provide for qmake building an app for ios ?

Comment: The sample isn't related to iOS directly at all, but just to inspect what environment is set by Qt Creator, you'd then diff it against your command line environment and see what's missing. The assumption that motivates this is that Qt Creator sets some environment variables that you don't know about. I presume that you have inspected the arguments that Qt Creator passes to qmake directly, right?

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the pointers. I go my script working now. I was doing another mistake i.e. I was running my script from root which did not pick the provisioning profile.